# 100% width nav across page wrapper

Tags: html, css, navigation, markup

i have a nav inside a site-wrapper,

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
...
</div>
```

the wrapper has a defined width of 960px + margin: 0 auto.
I want the Nav stretch over the whole 100% body width, across the 960px of the wrapper, without modifying the markup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely position the nav to 0,0 and set width to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nav elements are display inline by default, thats is why:

CSS:

```
nav {
   display: block;
}
```

there you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/TBqrA/

*edit* after you clarified you question: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/TBqrA/2/ you could use position absolute...

absolute positioned elements are positioned relatively to the next element that is position relative, fixed or absolute (or simply the body). Just make sure that you wrapper is position: static...

Comment: okay, maybe a misunderstanding.
let's say body width: 2000px, wrapper width:960px. The content is in the wrapper, the nav is in the wrapper too but should stretch over the whole 2000px(without taking the nav out of the wrapper).

Comment: aha! :P then the only way to go is using position absolute or fixed. Or have it outside you wrapper... unless you want do fiddle something with JS... (ps you don't want that :P )